# Does MySQL Connector/J read ~/.my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I have a Java application that uses MySQL with the Connector/J MySQL connector. I would like to specify the default client charset in the `$HOME/.my.cnf` file of the application user, so that it does not affect other applications on the same server.

To test whether Connector/J uses `$HOME/.my.cnf`, I created the file with the following content:

```
[client]
socket=/tmp/inexisting-mysql.sock
```

I expected that the Java application fails to connect to the database, because the `/tmp/inexisting-mysql.sock` does not exist. However, the application can still connect to the database successfully. It looks like Connector/J is not reading this configuration file at all.

How can I make Connector/J read the `$HOME/.my.cnf`? Or how can I specify a `[client]` section option for just my Java application, but not for other applications that use the same database?

Regards, Benedikt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default client charset for a connection you can give that as a [parameter to the connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) itself:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

I don't think there is a way to make Connector/J read your `$HOME/.my.cnf` out of the box. You could read that file in the java application and set the url parameter accordingly though.